# Further username and password problems

Tags: boot, usb, password

I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm testing out 14.04 on several netbook, tablet and tower platforms and am impressed by how easy trying & installing is compared to my first efforts 10 years back!

Both "Trying" and "Installing" from DVD works fine. However, for my netbook (without an optical drive) I use USB stick as the boot device which works up to the point it requests a Username & Password. No previous opportunity was offered to set these.  Older discussion on possible default settings have not yet helped in this case; ie V14.04 from USB stick.
All pointers welcome. 
THANKS ALL
Graham

Comment: Can you tell when/where exactly you get prompted for that password? And what default name/pw combinations did you already try?

Comment: It boots, I click Try Ubuntu, boot continues, next I get Login prompt [Username]. Usually I would get a list of short-cut keys and be allowed to continue.    I have tried username=ubuntu and psw=blank (and ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your bootable usb *may* be corrupt, though I have heard rumors of a username prompt being presented at startup. This seems to be unique to 14.04, so I suggest you either create a new bootable usb with the Startup Disk Creator and [a fresh 14.04 iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), or try installing a newer version, such as 15.04, to see if it's unique to that version, or if it's something to do with your computer, which I doubt. If you have a usb optical drive, I'd suggest trying that first with the install dvd you have, but it sounds like you don't possess one.

It would also be helpful if you provide the install log from your original install attempt, if possible.

Best of luck!

Comment: +1 It definitely sounds like a bad iso.  Try completely reflashing.  You may also have selected at some point to install Ubuntu to that USB, therefore creating a user account.  Not likely, but possible.

Comment: Thanks to Byte Commander, Dooley_labs & Daniel.  I find that creating the  usb boot stick within Ubuntu using Disk Image Writer gets round this. Previously I was using a method to create the boot stick within Windows which also brings this login problem.